# I have no password on my Mac but when I try to uninstall software it asks for a password which doesn't exist

Tags: password

I have a mac setup for running music programs.  It works fine and because I hate having to enter passwords I have none on anything on it.  No problems here and whenever I installed programs it would ask for the password I would just push enter and it would install no problem.  Now however I am trying to uninstall a program and when I do it pops up some terminal screen where it asks for a password... I push enter because there is no password on the machine and it says incorrect asks for the password again and does this 3 times before it closes down because I didn't enter the password.  Problem is there is no password so what is the way to skip this stupid loop to nowhere?

Comment: What program are you trying to uninstall? Are you running an uninstaller, or are you just dragging the program to the Trash?

Comment: If it's Terminal, that means the uninstaller is issuing a `sudo` command and `sudo` doesn't like blank passwords.  Put in a temporary password into your account and see if you can uninstall your software.  Once you do, you'll have to log out and back in.

Comment: I also suggest creating an "admin" account to do software installs and such and then you can create a "regular" account to can auto log into to do what you want.  Software (devs) is getting very security conscious nowadays so they're looking for authentications all over the place.  Best to accommodate it rather than fight it.

Comment: Was trying to uninstall real guitar by musiclabs, it started acting up so I was going to uninstall and reinstall it.  I guess I'll have to just put a password on the computer.  I assume I can just do that through the system preferences.